# AngularJS $watch iterator

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to access the angular $watch iterator?

I want to capture the first iteration through a $watch like this:

```
scope.$watch("var", myFunc);

myFunc() {
    if (iterator === 1) ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your watch function will get two arguments, the current value of "var" and the previous value. When your watch fires the first, both of these will be the same, so you can check for that to know if it's the first time it's called. Like this:

```
var myFunc = function(value, oldValue) {
    if (value === oldValue) {
        // First run
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but to be more direct to my question - is there no exposed iterator for the $watch function? Would I just have to create my own?

Comment: Angular doesn't give you a counter for how many times the watch have been executed, and I'm not sure why you would need it?